# Lagrange Interpolation In Python - Won't Print out

Tags: python, interpolation, polynomials

This is the problem I have to solve:

Write a program to evaluate and plot the Lagrange interpolant Iu(x) of u(x) = 1/(1+x^2) for x between -5 and 5. Do this for 5,7,9,11,13,15 point interpolants (5,7,9 etc. data points between, and including, -5 and 5). Your results should show both the function and the interpolant.

This is the code I have come up with so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def L_k(x, k, xp, yp):
    ans = 1
    for i in range(len(xp)):
        if i != k:
        ans *= (x - xp[i]) / (xp[k] - xp[i])
    return ans


def p_L(x, xp, yp):
    ans = 0
    for k in range(len(yp)):
        ans += yp[k] * L_k(x, k, xp, yp)
    return ans


def verify(xp, yp):
    status = 'Verified!'
    for k in range(len(xp)):
        if abs(p_L(xp[k], xp, yp) - yp[k]) > 1e-15:
            status = 'Error!'
            break
    print (status)


def verbose_verify(xp, yp):
    print  ('x', 'Exact', 'Approx', 'Difference')
    for k in range(len(xp)):
        x = xp[k]
        exact = yp[k]
        approx = p_L(xp[k], xp, yp)
        diff = abs(p_L(xp[k], xp, yp) - yp[k])
        print (x, exact, approx, diff)


def graph(f, n, xmin, xmax, resolution=1001):
    xlist = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, n)
    ylist = f(xlist)
    xlist_fine = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, resolution)
    ylist_fine = p_L(xlist_fine, xlist, ylist)
    plt.plot(xlist, ylist, 'ro')
    plt.plot(xlist_fine, ylist_fine)


def annotate_graph():
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('f(x)')
    ax.legend(['f(x)', 'Interpolated'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xlist = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 5)
    ylist = np.sin(xlist)
    verbose_verify(xlist, ylist)
    graph(np.sin, 5, 0, np.pi)
    annotate_graph()
    plt.show()
```

However it is not printing anything out. No error come up, there's just no output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Other than an indentation error in `def L_k(x, k, xp, yp):` on line `ans *= (x - xp[i]) / (xp[k] - xp[i])`, this code worked first time for me in Python 2.7

Comment: How are you running this? Do you see anything if you put a `print('Started')` directly under `if __name__ == '__main__':`? If so, how far do you get through those operations?